# Regarding Spring and Apache CXF Integration

Tags: web-services, spring, cxf

Inside the applicationcontext.xml file we have like this

```
  <bean id="vincent" class="com.bayer.vincent.service.vincent"/>

  <jaxws:endpoint
      id="vincentSOAP"
      implementor="#vincent"
      implementorClass="com.bayer.vincent.service.vincent"
      address="/vincent/soap"
      bindingUri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
```

what does this mean by this defination ??

My question is how the vincent class is being getting called ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CXF has provided a [custom spring namespace](http://javamoods.blogspot.com/2009/09/spring-use-custom-namespaces.html) to help easily configure a webservice endpoint here.

If the implementor starts with a #, CXF makes the assumption that the [endpoint is a Spring Bean](http://cxf.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/cxf/jaxws/spring/EndpointDefinitionParser.html), the way it is in your case.

The endpoint will have to be a normal JAX-WS endpoint, i.e annotated with @Webservice annotation, eg:

```
@WebService(serviceName="MemberService", endpointInterface="org.bk.memberservice.endpoint.MemberEndpoint", targetNamespace="http://bk.org/memberservice/")
```

Now any call to your uri-/vincent/soap, will be redirected by the CXF front controller(which you can register in the web.xml file):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

which maintains an internal registry of payload uri's to handlers(in this case the Spring bean) and dispatches the request appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand there created proxy class which forwards all calls to your real class.

See also [Configuring an Endpoint](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html) where described all `jaxws:endpoint` attributes.